# Add an additional form with django-registration

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a registration form that is rendered by the following urlconf --

```
url(r'^$',
    register,
    {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.UserBackend',
     'template_name': 'index.html'},
    name='auth_index'),
```

In the template, I have the following --

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

How would I add additional forms and context to this template? I want to be able to have something like the following --

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
...
<form action='{% url waiting_list %}' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
<p>Enter your email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""></p>
<input type="submit" name="email_submit" value="Submit Email">
</form> 
{{message}}
```

How could I do this? (Preferably, all within a view). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is OK.  Now you add the `waiting_list` url to your uelconf and implement it's view:

```
url(r'^waiting_list/$', 'myapp.views.waiting_list', {}, name='waiting_list'),
```

and:

```
   # myapp/views.py
   def waiting_list(request):
       ...
```

Since this is not data critical form, I would probably use `@csrf_exempt` to bypass csrf validation to makes thing easier.  In case of error,  redirect to an error page.

(BTW, usability wise, a better implementation for this problem might be posting the email with javascript.)

Comment: thanks, I've got this working. Two things -- should I be returning an `HttpResponseRedirect` with the waiting_list view (I'm currently doing return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth_index')). And second, how would I pass a message/template variable, for example, a success message after the user enters an email?

Comment: I would redirect to a kinda static "thank you page".  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/generic-views/#using-generic-views